# Quest and filter posts by author ID on author page

Tags: author-template

I'm building a custom author.php template. I use this to get the author by slug

```
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
```

Now my loop uses the author's ID like this

```
<div class="author-products">
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'author_id'=> $curauth->ID );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <li><div class="author-product-title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
         <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
            <a class="author-product-thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The loop is displaying all the posts and not filtering, is it a problem in the arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'author' => $curauth->ID`  instead of `'author_id'=> $curauth->ID` since `author_id` is not a valid parameter.